Download file with date Month_Year in filename from Web using Powershell
I need a Powershell job that will download a file from a website each month. The file includes the month and year in the name so I need some sort of variable or expression in the URL. I ran a test with the code below and it worked, but the name will change each month.
Invoke-WebRequest $https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_April_2024.zip -OutFile C:\Data\NPPES_Data_Dissemination_April_2024.zip 

I have an expression that will adjust the date each month but I don't think it works with powershell. Can something like this be used with Powershell?
"https://download.cms.gov/nppesNPPES_Data_Dissemination_"+ (MONTH(getdate()) == 1 ? "Jan" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 2 ? "Feb" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 3 ? "Mar" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 4 ? "April" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 5 ? "May" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 6 ? "Jun" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 7 ? "Jul" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 8 ? "Aug" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 9 ? "Sep" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 10 ? "Oct" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 11 ? "Nov" :
MONTH(getdate()) == 12? "Dec":"") + "_"+ (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("YEAR",GETDATE()) + ".zip"


By testing the URIs it seems the month should be actually not abbreviated, i.e. Jan_2024 fails but January_2024 works. Can you confirm this?

If the month names are as stated in the question, then neither GetMonthName or GetAbbreviatedMonthName will match these names. You may need to resort to a hardcoded list like you have. That will be a much larger problem if the code is ever run in a different locale where the month names are in a different language.

@SantiagoSquarzon Good point. This is the first month I've looked so I do not know the formatting of the other months. But if April is an indication, then I should proceed with the full name and not abbreviated.

I think you're looking for this:
"https://download.cms.gov/nppesNPPES_Data_Dissemination_$(Get-Date -Format "MMMM")_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy").zip"

Get-Date -Format can help you adjust your approach depending on the format your file (or whatever string) is saved as.
$("foo") lets you add functions within a string.
For example
Get-Date -Format "MM" 

Will display "04" (= April)
But be wary!
Get-Date -Format "mm"

will display minutes.
You can also omit the filename in -Outfile during the Invoke-Webrequest to use the websites name as filename.

This would do it... You may have to investigate get-culture if not returning value in english.
"https://download.cms.gov/nppesNPPES_Data_Dissemination_"+ `
(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).Month) + "_"+ `
(Get-Date).Year + `
".zip"

As well I see month naming is sometimes 3 letters or more. Not very consistent but not under your control as at website end. It may be worth checking this as well
"https://download.cms.gov/nppesNPPES_Data_Dissemination_"+ `
(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName((Get-Date).Month) + "_"+ `
(Get-Date).Year + `
".zip"


Given your example I presume the Month is always in English, in full and first letter uppercase
then:
# Get the date. Here is the dat at the time of the calling, 
# but you can just change it as necessary
$DateObject = Get-Date

# Convert date in a String, using the InvariantCulture as it has the
# month starting with uppercase so there is no need of further operations
# MMMM mean "month full name", the underscore is a literal and "yyyy" means full year
$DateString = $DateObject.ToString('MMMM_yyyy',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

# using the string formatting because is a little bit more clear in this case
$UriString = 'https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_{0}.zip' -f $DateString
$OutFileString = 'C:\Data\NPPES_Data_Dissemination_{0}.zip' -f $DateString

# Be Invoked, Ideon Gun, Tomino End, etc
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $UriString -OutFile $OutFileString

